# svnserve is allow anonymous users. how can i block them?

Tags: svn, svnserve

(sorry. my english skill is poor....)

today, i make a new SVN repository. here is my repository settings.

1. svnserve.conf

   ```
   [general]
   anon-access = none
   auth-access = write
   password-db = passwd
   ```
2. passwd

   ```
   [users]
   myusers = mypassword
   ```
3. restart svnserve

but, anon-users can access my repository. so, add a authz.

4. add authz infomation into svnserve.conf

   ```
   [general]
   anon-access = none
   auth-access = write
   password-db = passwd
   authz-db = authz
   ```
5. authz

   ```
   [groups]
   usergroup = myusers
   [/]
   @usergroup = rw
   ```
6. restart svnserve

but, anon-users still access my repo. how can i block them? my setting is something wrong??

Comment: what URL do you use to access the repository?

Comment: @bahrep svn://192.168.0.73/repositories
this is local access only. but, i want to control access each users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Read about Path-based autorization in SVN Book
2. Use good, brain-powered rules in authz-file. Starting point

```
[/]
$anonymous =
$authenticated = rw
```

Group with single member is stupid idea, single SVN-user for for all commiterrs is stupid idea, ignoring tokens in authz-file is bad idea